# Change the backgroundColor of nested div in NavLink in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom@6.5.0` but unable to style the `NavLink` component backgroundColor when route is active. This works when I insert some text just below `NavLink` tag.

```
    import {
  Box,
  CloseButton,
  Flex,
  Icon,
  useColorModeValue,
  Drawer,
  DrawerContent,
  Text,
  useDisclosure,
  BoxProps,
  FlexProps,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

import {
  FiHome,
  FiCalendar,
  FiBriefcase,
  FiDollarSign,
} from 'react-icons/fi';


import {
  IoPawOutline
} from 'react-icons/io5';

import { IconType } from 'react-icons';

import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from './Navbar';

<NavLink 
  to={to}
  style={({ isActive })=> ({
    background: isActive ? "green" : "blue",
  })}  
>  
  <Flex
    align="center"
    p="4"
    mx="4"
    borderRadius={["4px"]}
    role="group"
    cursor="pointer"
    _hover={{
      bg: '#1D3EAC',
      color: 'white',
    }}
    _active={{
      bg: '#1D3EAC',
      color: 'white',
    }}
  >
    {icon && (
      <Icon
        mr="4"
        fontSize="16"
        _groupHover={{
          color: 'white',
        }}
        as={icon}
      />
    )}
    {children}
  </Flex>
</NavLink>
```

Comment: This *looks* like it is correct. Can you clarify what you mean by "This works when I insert some text just below Navlink tag"? What isn't working otherwise?

Comment: For eg, `<NavLink 
       to={to}
       style={({ isActive })=> ({
        background: isActive ? "green" : "blue",
      })}  
      >This text will have background color  `

Comment: Could you [edit] the post to include the imports? I don't know what these `Flex` and `Icon` components are. Think you could also create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Added imports in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `children` render function of the `NavLink` to conditionally set the background color of the `Flex` component.

Example:

```
<NavLink to={to}>
  {({ isActive }) => (
    <Flex
      align="center"
      p="4"
      mx="4"
      borderRadius={["4px"]}
      role="group"
      cursor="pointer"
      _hover={{
        bg: "#1D3EAC",
        color: "white"
      }}
      _active={{
        bg: "#1D3EAC",
        color: "white"
      }}
      color="white"
      bg={isActive ? "green" : "blue"}
    >
      {icon && (
        <Icon
          mr="4"
          fontSize="16"
          _groupHover={{
            color: "white"
          }}
          as={icon}
        />
      )}
      {children}
    </Flex>
  )}
</NavLink>
```

[image]

You could also render the `Flex` component `as` a `NavLink`.

Example:

```
<Flex
  as={NavLink}
  to={to}
  align="center"
  p="4"
  mx="4"
  borderRadius={["4px"]}
  role="group"
  cursor="pointer"
  _hover={{
    bg: "#1D3EAC",
    color: "white"
  }}
  _active={{
    bg: "#1D3EAC",
    color: "white"
  }}
  color="white"
  style={({ isActive }) => ({
    background: isActive ? "green" : "blue"
  })}
>
  {icon && (
    <Icon
      mr="4"
      fontSize="16"
      _groupHover={{
        color: "white"
      }}
      as={icon}
    />
  )}
  {children}
</Flex>
```

[image]

Comment: `Value of type '({ isActive }: { isActive: any; }) => { backgroundColor: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'Properties<string | number, string & {}>'. Did you mean to call it?ts(2560)` It works though.

Comment: @Arif Ah, is this the `style` prop on the `Flex` component? Are you using Typescript? If you are not using Typescript you can probably ignore it. If you ***are*** using Typescript and this is a blocker then you'll probably need to use the first method unless you can change the `Flex` component's props type declaration. Sounds like you said it's all working for you though. You can probably ignore it.

Comment: Yeah, the first one works. Can you explain why my original code wasn't working. This is what it was mentioned in API of `React Router`

Comment: @Arif Without digging into the chakra-ui code to figure the exact cause/issue it seems the `Flex` component was simply overlaying the `anchor` tag. I could see that anchor tag had the correct background color applied to it in the DOM, but the flex `div` was hiding it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use function as a children for NavLink. One function params is boolean `isActive`.

```js
<NavLink to="/home">
  {({ isActive }) => (
    <span style={{ backgroundColor: isActive ? 'red' : 'blue'}}>link</span>
  )}
</NavLink>
```

Comment: It still isn't working. :(